# Why do I get 'UnicodeEncodeError'?

Tags: python

I have this code (warn: on URL content for adults only!)

```
# Encoding: UTF-8

import re
import requests
# import chardet

html = requests.get('http://klonedaset.org/news.php?sid=51854&bn=luRsF2aAa6eV63nU71Jm&ad=0&ref=&pt=&cookie=null&cls=null').text
text = re.findall('target=_blank id=.*?>(.*?)</a>', html)[0]
# print chardet.detect(text) return this "{'confidence': 0.9599621544520228, 'encoding': 'windows-1251'}"

open('file12.txt', 'a').write(text)
```

And I get this error on the last line (where I write in the file)

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I trying doing such as this

```
html = html.decode(windows-1251').encode('UTF-8')
```

But it doesn't work. I must write to the file in UTF-8!

Answer (score -1):

```
open('file12.txt', 'ab').write(text)
```

You need to open it for binary writing. Better use:

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open('file12.txt', mode="wb", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Also the URL is strange, it produces a broken page.

Comment: meh .. I just get high risk website blocked by chrome ... but I figured I would address the issue he was seeing

Comment: I re no block this site or not, but there you can see one pic and text in windows-1251. Also, dear Joran, into the file writing somethink like this "Ñûí âîñïîëüçîâàëñÿ ïüÿíûì æåëàíèåì ìàòåðè!"  :(